# Pass Calendar object to a server side method using JavaScript in ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, calendar

I have below `JavaScript` and i need to pass `Calendar` object to a method in partial class via function in `JavaScript`. I have a `asp:Calendar` in my web forms application. i need to pass an object of it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SelectDates() {
        PageMethods.selectAvlDates(/* what is here ? */);
    }
</script>
```

**C# code**

```
protected void Vehicle_Calendar_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
  e.Cell.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "SelectDates()"; // called java script function from here
}

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void selectAvlDates(Calendar cal)
{
    cal.SelectedDayStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: I don't think that you are trying to do may occur. But if you succeeded please inform me. I follow the post. Thx.

Comment: I am almost sure that you can not do such thing. Cannot serialize object with cyclic reference within child properties.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you could do something trick.

```
protected void Vehicle_Calendar_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
  string id = "xxx"; // Unique Id, Guid.New() for example
  e.Cell.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "SelectDates("+id+")"; 
  e.Cell.Attributes["id"] = "xxx";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function SelectDates(id) {
        $('td[id="'+id+'"]').css('backgroundcolor',"#FF0000"); // JQuery library should be referenced
        //PageMethods.selectAvlDates(/* what is here ? */);
    }
</script>
```

Hope that could help.